# knit2pdf failing to produce pdf in Shiny Apps

Tags: r, pdf, knitr, shiny

As the title states, I am attempting create a shiny application that can generate a pdf file that a user can then download. (Note that this is *not* a duplicate question because I have not found a question with a similar error)

In my search for a solution, I found this gist by the Knitr package author: https://gist.github.com/yihui/6091942, which I am attempting to recreate. There are also questions on S.O that use the same code, `out = knit2pdf('input.Rnw', clean = TRUE)` but all of them seem to date to before the 3.2.3 release of R.

The error I am given is:

```
output file: input.tex

Warning: running command '"pdflatex" -interaction=nonstopmode "input.tex"' had status 1
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  unable to run 'pdflatex' on 'input.tex'
Warning: Error in texi2dvi: unable to run 'pdflatex' on 'input.tex'
Stack trace (innermost first):
    52: texi2dvi
    51: tools::texi2pdf
    50: knit2pdf
    49: download$func [D:...\App-2/server.R#44]
     1: shiny::runApp
```

---

What I have tried so far:

Updating R, RStudio, knitr package and my TeX distribution (TeXLive). I know that TeXLive is not the issue as I use it daily, and I can create a dummy `.Rnw` that will compile perfectly using the Compile PDF button in R Studio. I have also tried using `knit()` or `render()` and those will generate `.tex` files without giving an error. I have also changed my working directory to the app folder as suggested by another S.O. question, but that didn't solve my problem either.

Edit, Additional information: I am using Windows 10

Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: What code do you actually use? Exactly the code in the referenced gist or code you wrote in your "attempt to recreate" the gist? Do you get the same error with `runGist('https://gist.github.com/yihui/6091942')`?

Comment: What platform are you on? There could be something funky with `texi2dvi` on Windows under TeXLive, where apparently this function is emulated. See [the tools::texi2dvi documentation, in the Details section](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/tools/texi2dvi)

Comment: @CL I lookee at the raw files on the gist and copied/pasted those, and it didn't work. I then tried runGist(...) and the app loaded, but produced the same error (as seen in my original post). If it helps, I can add a screenshot of what happens when running runGist(....)

Comment: @pneumatics thanks for the link. I'm using TexLive and it states "MiKTeX has a texi2dvi executable but no other Windows TeX installation that we know of does"... but surely there is a way to get knit2pdf working without changing my entire TeX distribution?  (when I checked the package manager for TexLive yesterday it said I already have texinfo 5.1)

Comment: If you're not attached to TeXLive, try switching to MiKTeX. I understand it's a pain to switch TeX distributions, but for what it's worth, I found it easy to install MiKTeX, and I haven't had to touch it once since.

Comment: @pneumatics the thing is I'm hoping to share my app and I don't want it system-specific: i.e. my friends with TeX Live should also be able to run my R code and generate pdfs

Comment: You won't have a dependency on MiKTeX if you use it. You may, however, be able to get that Shiny gist working! [Pandoc recommends MiKTeX for Windows](http://pandoc.org/installing.html), and TeXLive for Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think TeXLive is working completely. On Windows, RStudio recommends using MiKTeX, and [so does Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/installing.html).

Comment: To follow up on this solution: I recently upgraded my laptop HHD to a SSD and while reinstalling everything I tried this solution. I can confirm it works with MiKTeX on windows and TeXLive on linux on my dual boot